# Background image data not passing properly through graphql Gatsby query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

I think at this point I've just been looking at it too long and likely not seeing something obvious, but I can't figure out why my query is not properly getting background image data and instead appears as null. I'm using `"gatsby-background-image": "^1.1.1"` loaded in the package.json. I'm referencing my images file in my gatsby-config.js like this:

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
```

And the component using it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql, StaticQuery } from 'gatsby';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import BackgroundImage from 'gatsby-background-image';

const BackgroundSection = () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        desktop: file(relativePath: { eq: "demo.jpg" }) {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(quality: 90, maxWidth: 1920) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => {
      /* eslint-disable no-console */
      console.log(data);
      /* eslint-enable no-console */

      // Set ImageData.
      const imageData = data.desktop.childImageSharp.fluid;

      return (
        <BackgroundImage
          Tag="section"
          fluid={imageData}
          backgroundColor={`#040e18`}
        >
          <h2>gatsby-background-image</h2>
        </BackgroundImage>
      );
    }}
  />
);

const StyledBackgroundSection = styled(BackgroundSection)`
  width: 100%;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: cover;
`;

export default StyledBackgroundSection;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Changed some syntax to be more modern along with updating some dependencies so I'm honestly not entirely sure what fixed it but here is my [github compare](https://github.com/alleyhector/portfolio/compare/0ca16ce...d3a95f6) to show when it passed tests and when it didn't. At first this new syntax didn't seem to work either but did eventually pass data through.

In case anyone is curious my `bgimage.js` code eventually ended up looking like this:

````
import React from 'react';
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import BackgroundImage from 'gatsby-background-image';
import { theme } from '@styles';
const { colors } = theme;

/**
 * In this functional component a fullscreen <BackgroundImage />  is created.
 * @param className   string    className(s) from styled-components.
 * @param children    nodes     Child-components.
 * @return {*}
 * @constructor
 */
const FullBackground = ({ children }) => {
  const { desktop } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        desktop: file(relativePath: { eq: "bg/pompidou.jpg" }) {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(quality: 90, maxWidth: 3024) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp_tracedSVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `);

  // Watch out for CSS's stacking order, especially when styling the individual
  // positions! The lowermost image comes last!
  const backgroundFluidImageStack = [
    desktop.childImageSharp.fluid,
    `linear-gradient(${colors.alphaNavy}, ${colors.alphaNavy})`,
  ].reverse();

  return (
    <BackgroundImage
      Tag="section"
      fluid={backgroundFluidImageStack}
      title="Fullscreen Background"
      id="fullscreenbg"
      role="img"
      aria-label="Fullscreen Background"
      preserveStackingContext={true}
      style={{
        // Defaults are overwrite-able by setting one of the following:
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundPosition: 'center center',
        // backgroundRepeat: '',
        backgroundAttachment: 'fixed',
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </BackgroundImage>
  );
};

const StyledFullBackground = styled(FullBackground)`
`;

export default StyledFullBackground;```
````